# Xamarin IOS - Carousel View(Images) In Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement Images carousel View as per the below image.[image]

I want to display multiple images using carousel view with highlighted dots when user scroll the images (Highlight the respective dot below the image) in Xamarin IOS.

I tried with iCarousel - Xamarin Component ( [iCarousel Link](https://components.xamarin.com/view/icarousel) ) to display images with dots.
Here i am able to display the images in carousel view.
Can any one suggest me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want 3d effects, you can just use a scroll view with a page view control. Add the images in the scroll view and enable paging. Use scroll event function to move your view while changing the page control current Page. Not at a PC right now to send code